# when we do the sum of n numbers using for loop **ex.for(i=1;i<=n;i++)**

Tags: algorithm

when we do the sum of `n` numbers using for loop `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)`complexity of this is *O(n)*, but if we do this same computation using the formula of arithmetic/geometric progression series `n(n-1)/2` that time if we compute the time complexity, its *O(n^2)*. How ?  please solve my doubt.

Answer (score 2):

You are confused by what the numbers are representing.

Basically we are counting the # of **steps** when we talking about complexity.

`n(n+1)/2` is the answer of Summation(1..n), that's correct, but different way take different # of **steps** to compute it, and we are counting the # of such steps.

Compare the following:

```
int ans = 0;
for(int i=1; i<=n;i++) ans += i;
// this use n steps only

int ans2 = 0;
ans2 = n*(n+1)/2;
// this use 1 step!!

int ans3 = 0;
for(int i=1, mx = n*(n+1)/2; i<=mx; i++) ans3++;
// this takes n*(n+1)/2 step
// You were thinking the formula would look like this when translated into code!
```

All three answers give the same value!

So, you can see only the first method & the third method (which is of course not practical at all) is affected by `n`,  different `n` will cause them take different steps, while the second method which uses the formula, always take 1 step no matter what is `n`

Being said, if you know the formula beforehand, it is always the best you just compute the answer directly with the formula

Answer (score 1):

Your second formula has `O(1)` complexity, that is, it runs in constant time, independent of `n`.

There's no contradiction. The complexity is a measure of how long the algorithm takes to run. Different algorithms can compute the same result at different speeds.

[BTW the correct formula is `n*(n+1)/2`.]

Edit: Perhaps your confusion has to do with an algorithm that takes `n*(n+1)/2` steps, which is `(n^2 + n)/2` steps. We call that `O(n^2)` because it grows essentially (asymptotically) as `n^2` when `n` gets large. That is, it grows *on the order of* `n^2`, the high order term of the polynomial.

Comment: means you are saying that in the formula (n(n+1)/2) sorry for minus sign) n is not consider as algorithm input size. but consider only the last number.

Comment: Distinguish the math the program computes from the math we use to analyze how long it takes to run. A program that adds up `n` numbers will take `n` steps, independent of the numbers (assuming fixed-width integer math). That's `O(n)` complexity. A program that compares each of `n` numbers against each other will take `n*(n+1)/2` steps, which is `O(n^2)` steps [on the order of n^2] since `n^2` is a good approximation for how fast `n*(n+1)/2` grows when `n` is large. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/1682419 for a graph that shows the dramatic difference between Big-O complexities.